# Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade crashes machine

Tags: boot, upgrade, 22.04

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. This upgrade worked, and the Software Updater advertised an upgrade to 22.04. I selected to start that upgrade.

Once that upgrade finished it produced an error saying the upgrade was partial and broken.

I restarted the machine, and now I get an error about failed livepatch: Failed to start Service fo*ivepatch.canonical-livepatchd. I am unable to restart the machine thus far. What I have tried:

- I have tried using GRUB Advanced options for Ubuntu, but these end saying to press CTRL-D to continue. The machine is unresponsive to pressing CTRL-D or Enter.
- I tried booting off a USB ISO image of Ubuntu 20.04. Thus far GRUB is not recognizing this.

I did not backup my files unfortunately. Is there anyway I can at least access my files in a safe mode to download them before wiping the machine? Is there anyway to repair the upgrade or revert to 20.04 without wiping the machine?

I have seen no other answers that address this issue clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Load a live Ubuntu environment from a USB stick and access your files from there

Comment: I downloaded an Ubuntu ISO to a stick. It isn't that simple. It doesn't even read the ISO. Fortunately, I could get to a terminal to download the files at least.

Comment: @yellowjacket05 just copying an ISO is not enough. I recommend using Ventoy for that